# Css styling in Internet Explorer versus Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I`m working on the website based on blogger platform and I have a problem with  css styling. 
The website is: http://wibracjezdrowia.blogspot.com/p/opinie-klientow.html 
Problem: In Chrome browser everything is working okey but when I check in Internet Explorer than there is a problem with position of logo and green sign "GABINET TERAPII NATURALNYCH" - I mean that there are not in one row as they appear in Chrome. 
Can anyone help to solve this problem?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer shows this problem?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the OP's issue on IE 11

Comment: I have figured out the issue let me write answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the size of #header div.

You can change the max-width of this div to a lower value and it should be fine:

```
#header {
float: right;
width: 100%;
max-width: 690px;
color: #444;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

I've changed the max-width from 735px to 690px and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much of an answer to the direct issue, but have you considered using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to more easily style the elements of your website for desktop and mobile use?

Answer (score 0):

Just before `</head>` (closing head tag) add the following code to target only IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style>
        *, *::before, *::after{box-sizing: content-box}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```